# Not able to execute a Jenkins pipeline because of syntax issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following Jenkinsfile in the root of my Spring Boot based project which gets executed in Jenkins and builds the project.

I am quite new to Jenkins pipeline syntax. Any help will be greatly appreciated

**Jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        maven "Maven3"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                node {
                    def os = System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase()
                    echo "OS: ${os}"                
                    if (os.contains("linux")) {
                      sh "mvn clean install -DskipTests" 
                    } else {
                      bat "mvn clean install -DskipTests"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Jenkins Error Log:**

```
WorkflowScript: 10: Expected a step @ line 10, column 6.
                    def os = System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase()
        ^

WorkflowScript: 12: Expected a step @ line 12, column 6.
                    if (os.contains("linux")) {
        ^

WorkflowScript: 9: Missing required parameter: "label" @ line 9, column 5.
                node {
       ^

3 errors

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:131)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:560)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:521)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:320)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

**UPDATED ERROR LOG AFTER TRYING THE PROVIDED SOLUTION**

```
Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods getProperties java.lang.Object. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods getProperties java.lang.Object
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectStaticMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:189)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor$8.reject(SandboxInterceptor.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:403)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:292)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:11)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor241.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:121)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:182)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) There are two types of pipeline in jenkins.
Declarative and Scripted.
You mixed two types of syntax and keyword's from both.

`node` is a keyword for scripted pipeline. 
But in beggining of script you declared Pipeline script. So to fix this error, you need remove `node`.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/

2) For using condition statement you need wrap it with in a `script` 
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-steps

3) You need to approve or whitelist your script.
Go to Manage Jenkins -> In-process Script Approval. And press approve.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/

the final result

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        maven "Maven3"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {

                script {
                    def os = System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase()
                    echo "OS: ${os}"                
                    if (os.contains("linux")) {
                      sh "mvn clean install -DskipTests" 
                    } else {
                      bat "mvn clean install -DskipTests"
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Let me try this quickly and update you.

Comment: Didn't work :( I have updated the original post with new error that I am getting now

Comment: @user2325154 Updated answer, you need to approve your script in Manage Jenkins -> In-process Script Approval.